# Controlling mold mites

Tags: pest-control

I found a LOT of small white specks moving around on my monitor. I found out they were mold mites, which eat mold and are found near moisture. They are relatives of the dust mite, a common allergen. How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to eliminate the mold than to try to kill the mites. This avoids use of dangerous pesticides the likelihood of the mites recurring.

To reduce mold,

1. Reduce humidity, either with ventilation, a dehumidifier or absorbent such as calcium chloride.
2. Remove anything the mold eats, e.g. old papers or food. Vacuum thoroughly.
3. If mold is a problem in a specific area, it can be temporarily removed with chlorine bleach or [CO2 blasting](https://www.continentalcarbonic.com/mold-remediation.html). If the conditions causing mold are not fixed, the mold can be expected to return.

See more on mold removal at [Family Handyman](http://www.familyhandyman.com/cleaning/mold-and-mildew/how-to-remove-mold/view-all).

You might try garden miticides, but they may have health dangers.